# Square of Natural numbers is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Determine whether or not the below set

$A=\{a^2|a \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is countable.

I think the set of squares of natural numbers is countable and I can use the below mapping

$f(N)=N^2$

$1\mapsto1\\2\mapsto4\\3\mapsto9\\4\mapsto16\\.\\.\\.$

Am I correct in my approach?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "countable."

Comment: @CameronBuie: In which definition of “countable” is the set of squares not countable?

Comment: @celtschk: None that I'm aware of. I just mean that if the OP has a particular definition to demonstrate that $A$ satisfies, it would be good to know what it is, so we can better say whether the approach given is optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, formally define $f$, as follows; $f:\mathbb{N}\to A$ is defined by $f(n)=n^2$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now, you just have to prove $f$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$. To do so, show it's injective and surjective; that is, show that if $f(a)=f(b)$ then $a=b$ and for every $c\in A$ there's some $d\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(d)=c$.

Now that you've found a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$, you can conclude $A$ is countable.

Comment: Technically, for a mapping $f: \mathbb{N} \to A$, you only need to prove that it’s surjective. If the mapping was $f: A \to \mathbb{N}$, then you’d only need to prove that it’s injective.

Comment: @Joe Sure, but that's something one has to prove; I don't think it's worth the time, as proving $f$ is injective is simple.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. A set $X$ is countable if, and only if, there exists a mapping between the set of natural numbers and $X$. You've done exactly that!

Now, as Yuval Gat has said, you need to prove that your function $f$ is indeed bijective:

- It is injective, because if there are $a$ and $b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$, then $a^2=b^2$, so $a= \pm b$, but $a$ and $b$ are both naturals, so the only possibility is $a=b$
- It is surjective, because if $y \in A$, then $\exists x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^2=y$. Therefore $y = f(x)$, in other words, $f \in Im(f)$

Of course there are simpler arguments (for instance, every subset of a countable set is countable), but of course this depends on what previous results you're "allowed" to use